# Родинний та фамільний?

Tags: синоніми, запозичені-слова, прикметники, розмовна-українська

Чи завжди можливо замінити прикметник *"родинний"* прикметником *"фамільний"*?

В академічному тлумачному словнику можна знайти обидва слова і вони вважаються синонімами, однак слово *"родинний"* має набагато більше визначень, тому чи правильно буде виконувати такі заміни: *"родинне село"* - *"фамільне село"*, *"родинне гніздечко"* - *"фамільне гніздечко"*, тощо?

Чи все ж таки ці слова не можна вважати абсолютними синонімами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [Словнику української мови 1970-1980 рр.](http://sum.in.ua/s/rodynnyj) подають такі статті:

> **РОДИ́ННИЙ**, а, е. 1. *прикм. до родина*
>
> 1. Взагалі *родинне життя* надзвичайно якось скоро увійшло в свою колію (Гнат Хоткевич, II, 1966, 11)
>
> /  Який належить родині, сім'ї.
>
> Воля витягла з шафи оберемок старої *родинної одежі* й пожбурила на ліжко (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954, 89)
>
> /  Який переходить від покоління до покоління.
>
> — Написала в листі, що це ковзани не прості, а майже *родинна реліквія* (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 589).
>
> /  Який здійснюється, відбувається за участю членів родини, сім'ї.
>
> *На родинній нараді* було вирішено, що я мушу вчитися, дійти до інженера, а то й ще вище (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954, 17)
>
> /  Який складається з членів родини, сім'ї.
>
> *Родинне коло* діда оточило, Сини та дочки, й молоді онуки (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 52).
>
> 2. Стос. до родини (у 1 знач.), пов'язаний з життям родини, в родині.
>
> Нездорові *родинні обставини*, розлад батьками, міщанський побут, надмірне потурання дитячим примхам негативно впливають на виховання дітей (Історія української літератури, II, 1956, 222).
>
> 3. Притаманний, власт. рідним (про почуття, стосунки, ставлення).
>
> Племінник не дуже любив свого дядю, але мусив підтримувати тісні *родинні взаємини* (Оксана Іваненко, Тарас. шляхи. 1954, 190)
>
> 4. діал. В якому народився і виріс хто-небудь; рідний (у 4 знач.).
>
> Панщина вигнала мене *з родинного гнізда* і з порядного господаря зробила жебраком (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 196)

Щодо прикметника "фамільний", там же знаходимо таку інформацію:

> **ФАМІ́ЛЬНИЙ**, а, е. 1. ***заст***, ***діал***.. *Прикм. до фамілія* 2; родовий.
>
> Це була натура добра зроду, але зовсім попсована фамільними традиціями панства (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 39).

Аби точніше зрозуміти, зіертаємось до пропонованої нам статті про значення слова "фамілія":

> 1. ***розм**.* Те саме, що прізвище
> 2. — Він якогось пана підписаря підписар, чи що! Фамілія його — Серединський (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 122).
> 3. ***заст***. Рід (у 2 знач.).
>
> Ми всім селом у дивізію пішли, а на селі у нас якраз дві фамілії: Довгоруки та Семиволоси (Юрій Смолич, Театр.., 1940, 122).
>
> 3. ***діал***. Родина, члени родини. — Бувай здоров, Орлюче! Кланяйся від нас своєму дому і всій фамілії (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 323).

Отже, ці слова є синонімам, відмінність лише у тому, що "родинний" - той, що стосується родини; такий прикметник можна використовувати у будь-якому стилі, зокрема і науковому, й офіційно-діловому. Щодо "фамільний", то це той, що стосується безпосередньо фамілії. Таким чином, якщо приглянутися до самих міток, що подає СУМ-20 у кожній наведеній мною статті, то побачимо, що лексема "фамільний" є дещо застарілою і використовується лише у розмовному стилі та діалектах.

Comment: У запитанні автор посилається на СУМ, тому цитату можна було б і не таку розлогу пропонувати… :)

Answer (score 1):

Згідно із **[Словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)** ***"родинний"*** та ***"фамільний"*** є повними синонімами.

> **РОДИ́ННИЙ, СІМЕ́ЙНИЙ, РОДИЧІ́ВСЬКИЙрозм.,ФАМІ́ЛЬНИЙ (розм.), ФАМІЛІ́ЙНИЙ   (розм.);ДОМА́ШНІЙ, ДОМО́ВИЙ.** - Пор. 1. роди́на.
>
> **СПАДКО́ВИЙ** (про фізичні й духовні якості - який передається наступним поколінням), **ВРО́ДЖЕНИЙ, РОДОВИ́Й, РОДИ́ННИЙ, ФАМІ́ЛЬНИЙ**
>   (заст.), **ФАМІЛІ́ЙНИЙ** (заст.), діал.- *Щоправда, характер поганий.
>   Але ж, батеньку мій, усім не догодиш!.. Потім, можливо, це в нього
>   спадкове* (О. Довженко); *Очі в графині жовті, не такі, як у Лукії,
>   але це родове, графи Скаржинські завжди мали такі очі, круглі, жовті й
>   пронизливі* (О. Донченко).

***В усній мові можемо вживати ці слова, як взаємозамінні.***